# Is there a way to change the value of a variable through multi threads in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a variable `int a` which I want to change its value through 4 threads in Qt.

For example I have `class A : public QThread` and I want to have a global variable (`int a`) such that I can change its value from every threads.

```
A** baseThread=new A*[4];
for(int m=0;m<4;m++)
{
    baseThread[m] = new A();
    baseThread[m]->start();
}
```

and in `run` function:

```
void A::run()
{
    ...
    a+=qrand();
    ...
}
```

So after the execution of the last thread, `a` is the sum of 4 random values.

How can I do that?

Comment: May I ask what's the point of this?

Comment: I recommend you share data between threads at the minimum, and if you are going to do it use the mutex, but even so it is difficult to synchronize, do not abuse the threads

Comment: Unless you're redefining how threading works in Qt, I suggest you don't inherit from `QThread`. You're better off using `QThread` as described [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). You can use Qt's signals and slots to change the value on a single thread; signalled from the other threads.

Comment: `qrand()` is probably initialized with your local time. You could create 4 QTimer::singleShot with 200, 400, 600, 800 ms delay from one thread and it would archive completely the same without the mutex/synchronization pain.

Comment: @user3606329 thanks, the real problem is not this, I want to have a trick in inserting records in database with 4 threads.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for your answer

Comment: @TheDarkKnight thanks, I will try your solution, and I will come back here again.